# How to Resolve "error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, libraries, shared-library, swift

I installed Swift for Ubuntu using the latest toolchain available. At the time of writing, that version is 5.4.3. I downloaded it from https://swift.org/download/#releases

I installed many dependencies including `python3` and `python-dev-is-python3` as I have seen mongodb do in order to support Ubbuntu 20.04. However, attempting to run `swift` still prints,

```
/usr/share/swift/usr/bin/lldb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you’ve downloaded is built for Python 3.7; Ubuntu 20.04 includes Python 3.8.

You need to download [the Ubuntu 20.04 build of Swift](https://swift.org/builds/swift-5.4.3-release/ubuntu2004/swift-5.4.3-RELEASE/swift-5.4.3-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04.tar.gz), which is built for Python 3.8.